# SSH: one user logs in, other don't

Tags: ssh, sftp

Some users can ssh correctly, others don't.
I have an admin user, which is in wheel. 
I used vsftpd for allowing FTP. I created a nologin user for FTP. Call this user "ftpuser".
Now I want to allow sftp. 
It allows me to connect using admin user.
I remove the nologin, by giving the user a shell via `usermod -s /bin/bash ftpuser`.
It still doesn't allow me to connect from the ftpuser via sftp.
The content of `/home/ftpuser/.ssh` is just the `known_hosts` file which contains "localhost" entry only.

User permissions are (in theory) ok:

```
ls -la /home
    working (admin)     : drwx------ 18 admin  admin 4096 Feb  6 15:33 admin
    non-working(ftpuser): drwx------  3 ftpuser ftp   4096 Mar 26 15:25 ftpuser
```

I haven't configured anything special on openssh. Does the ftpuser need anything *extra* than shell to enter via ssh?

Comment: What does **/var/log/auth.log** say about both users?

Comment: Maybe a side note, but I think it's better practice to use FTPS with TLS.

Comment: Or /var/log/secure on RHEL/CentOS.

Comment: @LucasKauffman Why do you think FTPS is better than SFTP/SCP?  Considering the greater use of SSH/SFTP/SCP, better client support, more flexibility, and the advantage of all access being across a single port, I'd lean very heavily towards SFTP/SCP almost every time.  About the only thing I think FTP is even remotely good for (encrypted or not) is for file distribution via anonymous FTP.

Answer (score 0):

/var/log/auth.log will give you more details.

There are a few things that could be wrong.  I'd start by checking the permissions on the /home/ftpuser/.ssh directory.  OpenSSH may refuse to let you login if the permissions on that directory are incorrect (since malicious people could put public keys in there if you allow write access)

Try connecting with just ssh instead of sftp to see if it's a problem with sftp itself.

Also check your SSHd config file to see if there are restrictions on who is allowed to login.  It may be limited to users in wheel.